Could I use present perfect here because of present relevance?

When I saw that this record would be released in France, I felt happy: I ordered it. But when I realized the French version would only have two tracks instead of the original four, I felt disappointed.

As the record has not arrived can I stick to present perfect 'I have ordered it'?
I think I can because it has a present relevance.
Can it be the same with "feeling disappointed" if I am still feeling disappointed:  'I have felt disappointed'?
Anyway  I think present perfect sounds a bit odd here

Side note: I think found out or learned may be better than realized there.  The word realized refers to a deduced conclusion that suddenly comes to you.  Something like "It can't contain all four tracks. The total time is only 12 minutes 26 seconds" would be a realization.

You ask these or similar questions over and over.

This question is similar to: Simple Past vs. Present Perfect. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The ordering is past, and hence I ordered it is right.   Similarly the feeling of
disappointment happened upon the realisation and should be in the past too, I felt disappointed.
The present perfect may be used in
Now I see that the French version would only have two tracks; I am disappointed as I have ordered it.
I have felt disappointed earlier but am better now.

Yes - I have felt disappointed  could imply that you no longer do so, but presumably the feeling continues.

so i am feeling disappointed  or I have been feeling disappointed since  then

With regard to the present perfect, I disagree with this answer. OP’s intuition is correct—once the order has been placed and until it has been delivered, one can say, “I have ordered it.”   That situation is exactly analogous to what I myself wrote in the previous sentence: “once the order has been placed.” The simple-past ordered is ambiguous about whether the order has been fulfilled yet, while the present past have ordered implies that it has not.
